# Optimizing speed of updating changed key/value pairs and serializing to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, optimization, binaryformatter

My project involves capturing desktop frames and sending to a receiving device via a TCP socket for rendering, I want to minimize the latency between frames as much as possible, prefereably under 50ms in total.

The data being sent is a DirectX DataStream as a byte array, which just represents the colour of each pixel.

For a 1920x1080 display, this results in a byte array with a length of 8294400, using `Stream.CopyTo` takes under 10ms which is reasonable.

Compressing that resulting byte array using LZ4 reduces this down to a length of 631126 bytes, taking an additional 10ms or so.

I would prefer to reduce this size even further, by only sending changed pixels.

My first thought is to use a `Dictionary<int,int>` to store a cache of the pixels from last frame sent and then compare with the new frame:

```
private Dictionary<int, int> CachedPixels = new Dictionary<int, int>();

...

DataRectangle dataRect = surface.Map(SharpDX.DXGI.MapFlags.Read, out DataStream dataStream);

using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(dataStream))
    int pixels = (int)(dataStream.Length / 4); //4 bytes per BGRA colour
    Dictionary<int, int> changedPixels = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < pixels; i++) {
        int col = br.ReadInt32();

        if(!CachedPixels.ContainsKey(i)) {
            CachedPixels.Add(i, col);
            changedPixels.Add(i, col);
        } else {
            if(col != CachedPixels[i]) {
                CachedPixels[i] = col;
                changedPixels.Add(i, col);
            }
        }
    }

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, newCache);
    
    return LZ4.Compress(ms.ToArray());
```

But this is really slow.

If I use `StopWatch` to calculate the time taken:

The first frame with all 2073600 pixels has the loop taking 170ms and serializing with `BinaryFormatter` takes 2100ms.

Then a next frame updating 379902 pixels has the loop taking 75ms and serializing takes 356ms.

How could I optimize this?

Comment: Years ago, I made something similar, but not for images. I'd consider the entire area as many small blocks (i.e. 64x64 pixels, for instance). For every frame, calculate a hash over each block, then keep them in a matrix. At that point, you can detect whether a hash is changed and send the related block content. Overall, not an easy task, though.

Comment: Why not just ask ffmpeg to capture your desktop and stream it? That way you don't end up reimplementing ffmpeg

Comment: Simply put, my use case does not support ffmpeg due to limitations of gdigrab/dshow.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a Dictionary is really hindering your performance. Instead, retain the memory stream from the last screen capture, set its position back to 0, and read it along with the new stream from the new capture and do your comparison. This will drastically improve your comparison time.

I can add example code when I'm at a computer. Basically:

1. For the very first capture, set var lastStream = data from screen capture and send all data as changed
2. Begin your capture loop here and set var currentStream = data from screen capture
3. Instantiate binary readers for each stream
4. Perform your integer comparisons for each pixel using the binary readers
5. Run Dispose() on lastStream
6. Set lastStream = currentStream (reference variables for the win!)
7. Use a separate task to send the changes over the network so your next frame process iteration isn't waiting on network IO
8. Continue the loop to read the next capture, which will set the value of currentStream

This will run much faster than having conditional logic and treeing through two dictionaries.